# How to get Runtime to create A audio file using FFMPEG in OSX

Tags: java, bash, shell

This code is very similar to many other posts code concerning this issue, however, I cannot seem to get the code working. Could someone please offer some advice on where I am going wrong, thank you.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args)  {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Users/NN/desktop/ffmpeg -i aud.mp3 a.wmv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code/error-messages; post the text itself.

Comment: As the error message tells you, you are trying to run something called "/Users/NN/desktop", which presumably is the name of the folder, not the script.

Comment: I fixed the error message already, that wasn't the final problem.

Comment: We don't need to know how your whole day went. Could you edit this question down to just the actual problem you're having now? People aren't going to wade through a long narrative full of irrelevant information. And replace your screenshots of code with the actual code in textual form.

Comment: Shortened it up for you bud, can you give me my point back, please.

Comment: So are you going to attempt to answer the question? or is your job just to down-vote people and disappear?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] command = {"/Users/NN/desktop", "script.sh", "Argument1"};
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

You are trying to execute the program `/Users/NN/desktop`. Unsurprisingly, this isn't a program, so you can't run it. You are trying to run it with two arguments - "script.sh" and "Argument1".

You wanted to run the actual script:

```
String[] command = {"/Users/NN/desktop/test/script.sh", "Argument1"};
```

Comment: I also tried that already, which produces the same result, or lack there of. Still no file output.

Comment: I was able to get a screen print of "hello world" type text, however, I want the script to run outside of java, with java just activating the terminal to pop up and run the script, and then create the new media format. How might this be accomplished?